# How to generate Android AppUrl?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paytm

Can any one know how to generate AppUrl in android Studio . My application is in development phase , so I don't have PlayStore app url . Anyone know the alternative of that ??

- Note- It is not upload on playstore , it is in developing phase so i dont have playstore appurl .
- Is any way to achieve or get appurl before uploading it to play store ???
- I want something like this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing . But i am not getting how to achieve it .

Earlier Reply is appreciable

Comment: why would you need app url before uploading your app to playstore ?

Comment: @Qasim i need to integrate some payment gateways , on that i need to add appurl

Comment: @Qasim i think its of normal use, some links must be there before app is launched, like rate us etc

Comment: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>` easiest way

Comment: @NICK check my answer it surely help to you.

Comment: @InsaneCat can you Please share your code , its help me to understand better

Answer (score 0):

Your app url will be
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="your app package name"`

Comment: Thanks for your early reply , As i already mention Above , my app is in developing phase . Its not yet published on play store .

Comment: That's why I said, "it will be".

Answer (score 0):

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplication().getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
        // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplication().getPackageName())));
        }
```